# How to normalize a list of floats when one value has to stay the same?

Tags: python, list, floating-point, normalize

I have a list with these normalized values

```
list_a = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
```

Now I want to change the value of one entry to another number, let's say `0.75`. This number is fixed and shouldn't change anymore.

```
list_a_changed = [0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.25]
```

To still make sure the sum of all the values in the list add up to `1`, the remaining values need to be `0.0833`. So my list will have to be:

```
list_a_normalized = [0.083, 0.083, 0.75, 0.083]
```

This is easy enough to figure out if all values share the same percentage in the initial list. I can just do `1 - 0.75 = 0.25`, and divide that `0.25` between remaining numbers since they all hold the same percentage of the total sum.

```
value_change = 0.75
remaining_value = 1 - value_change
divided_remaining_value = remaining_value / (len(list_a_changed) - 1)

list_a_normalized = [divided_remaining_value, divided_remaining_value, value_change, divided_remaining_value ]
```

But how would you do it if the original list was something like:

```
list_b = [0.25, 0.45, 0.20, 0.10]
```

And I change one value to `0.05`

```
list_b_changed = [0.25, 0.45, 0.05, 0.10]
```

How would you calculate what the values of the other numbers will have to be so they each hold the appropriate portion of the remaining `0.95`?

Comment: You can always force all the remaining values to be the same, so the first algorithm is still valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may

- compute the `remaining`
- compute the total without the changed value, to get their relative proportion without the changed value
- multiply their value to the remaining to get it into account, and divide by the relative total to get them proportionnate to the total

```
def normalize(values, index_not_change):
    remaining = 1 - values[index_not_change]
    total_except_remaining = sum(values) - values[index_not_change]
    return [(value * remaining / total_except_remaining if idx != index_not_change else value)
            for idx, value in enumerate(values)]

print(normalize([0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.25], 2)) # [0.0833333333, 0.0833333333, 0.75, 0.0833333333]
print(normalize([0.25, 0.45, 0.05, 0.10], 2)) # [0.296875, 0.534375, 0.05, 0.11875000000000001]
```

---

To understand the `total_except_remaining` purpose, without it it'd have been that

```
normalize([0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.25], 2) -> [0.0625, 0.0625, 0.75, 0.0625]
```

because you'd have compute a quarter of the remaining (`0.25`) but adding the fact that the relative sum was `0.75` and not 1, you update to their real proportion

---

You can put the modification in the same method too

```
def normalize(values, position, new_value):
    values[position] = new_value
    remaining = 1 - new_value
    total_except_remaining = sum(values) - new_value
    return [(value * remaining / total_except_remaining if idx != position else value)
            for idx, value in enumerate(values)]

print(normalize([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25], 2, 0.75))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `change_normalized` item and keep the list normalized: 
The `re_normalize` keeps the list normalized by multiplying with the correct factor (which is the ratio between one and the sum without the changed item):

```
def change_normalized(lst, index, value):
    def touch(lst, index, value):
        lst[index] = value
    def re_normalize(lst, index, value):
        multiply_factor = (1 - value) / (sum(lst) - value)
        for j in range(len(lst)):
            if i == j:
                continue
            lst[j] *= multiply_factor
    touch(lst, i, value)
    re_normalize(lst, i, value)

i = 2
value = 0.05
list_b = [0.25, 0.45, 0.20, 0.10]

# Change item at index to value and keep list normalized
change_normalized(list_b, i, value)

# 1.0
print(sum(list_b))
```

This code can be shrinked to:

```
def change_normalized(lst, index, value):
    lst[index] = value
    multiply_factor = (1 - value) / (sum(lst) - value)
    lst[:] = [multiply_factor * x if i != j else x for j, x in enumerate(lst)
```